# Android GCM get Registered Users Google Account credentials

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In my application i have successfully integrated the GCM api to register user devices and to sent notifications from webservice to the mobile devices. 
I want to know if it is possible to get Google account credentials for the user during the registration process. ie : If the user has more than one Google accounts synced with a device, then i want to determine which account is used for getting the GCM user id in this scenario.
Is there a way to determine this?

Answer (score 0):

The GCM use primary account - first account that you set up with device.But you can not determinate close code of GCM.

Comment: So does this mean there can be no solid way  of determining which particular account is used for registration? Or can i take the first account as the primary by default?

Comment: Yes,you can take your primary account for  gcm registration